# Is the Qatari emir's position on Israel the official position of its government?

Tags: israel, qatar

> Qatar’s Emir Sheikh Tamim bin Hamad Al Thani has accused the
> international community of “turning their back” on the Palestinian
> people amid Israel’s bombardment of Gaza while calling for a permanent
> ceasefire in the besieged enclave.
>
> In his opening remarks at the Gulf Cooperation Council (GCC) summit in
> Doha on Tuesday, the emir accused Israel of committing a “genocide” in
> Gaza, noting that the “crimes” of Israeli forces help “deepen the
> sentiment of injustice and an absence of international legitimacy”.

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/12/5/qatar-emir-condemns-genocide-in-gaza-urges-ceasefire-at-gcc-summit

> The political system of Qatar is a semi-constitutional monarchy with
> the emir as head of state and chief executive, and the prime minister
> as the head of government. Under the Constitution of Qatar, the
> partially-elected Consultative Assembly has a limited ability to
> reject legislation and dismiss ministers. The 2nd general election was
> held in 2021.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Qatar

The emir claimed Israel was committing genocide. Since the emir is the head of state and chief executive, can we assume that Qatar official position on Israel actions against Hamas is that Israel is committing a genocide, or this is not the official position of Qatar just like Biden's position on certain issue is not necessarily the official U.S. position.

Comment: "certain issue" being the "war criminal" quip [among others], I guess. BTW, a number of other countries' leaders (including--unsurprisingly--Iran's Supreme Leader) had made similar g-word statements in re Israel, as did North Korea etc. I guess a good related Q would be though if any countries with US bases did that, besides Qatar and Iraq (Al-Sudani also said that on a visit to Iran.)

Comment: @Fizz - Gee, I wonder what the North Korean government's motivation for calling out Israel could be. Is it because of its well-known commitment to human rights, or just its support of fellow Muslims?